# Find the other 2 points of a rectangle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

$PQRS$ is a rectangle with vertices $P(-4,-1)$ and $Q(-6,5),$ and $PQ=2(QR).$ Find the coordinates of $R$ and $S$? I'm so stuck please help!
There are 2 answers for each point. almagest has the right answers, but i need work for it. I know that the slope of PS and QS has to be 1/3. But i tried making systems and I can't figure out how to solve for the other point. I also know the distance of PQ is 2(radical 10) so the distance of PS and QR have to be 4 (radical 10)

Comment: With the information you have provided, there are two possibilities for the location of the other vertices. Are you sure you haven't left out any information?

Comment: It would help to have more information about what tools you know (and why they didn't work here) in order to know what would help you. Can you find the equation of a line through two points? A line through a given point perpendicular to a given line?

Comment: R(-3,6) S(-1,0) or R(-9,4) S(-7,-2)

Comment: There are 2 answers for each point. almagest has the right answers, but i need work for it. I know that the slope of PS and QS has to be 1/3. But i tried making systems and I can't figure out how to solve for the other point. I also know the distance of PQ is 2(radical 10) so the distance of PS and QR have to be 4 (radical 10)

Comment: @ShelbyApplegate: I suggest to edit your question by inserting your comment at the end. Maybe that will address the "off-topic" complaint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the vertices are written consecutively, $\overline{PQ}$ is a side of the rectangle.  Its slope is

$m_{\overline{PQ}} = \dfrac{-1 - 5}{-4 - (-6)} = \dfrac{-6}{2} = -3$

Since the sides of a rectangle are perpendicular, the slope of $\overline{QR}$ must be the negative reciprocal of $-3$, which is $1/3$.

If you use the point-slope equation of a line

$y - y_0 = m(x - x_0)$

you can write the equation of the line containing $\overline{QR}$ in the form

$y - 5 = \dfrac{1}{3}(x + 6)$

You want to find a point $R$ on the line such that the distance between $P$ and $Q$ is twice the distance between $Q$ and $R$.  The distance between $P$ and $Q$ is

$d(P, Q) = \sqrt{[-6 - (-4)]^2 + [5 - (-1)]^2} = \sqrt{(-2)^2 + 6^2} = \sqrt{4 + 36} = \sqrt{40} = 2\sqrt{10}$

The distance between $Q$ and $R$ is thus $\sqrt{10}$.  The distance between $R(x, y)$ and $Q(-6, 5)$ is

$d(Q, R) = \sqrt{(x + 6)^2 + (y - 5)^2} = \sqrt{10}$

Squaring both sides of the equation yields

$(x + 6)^2 + (y - 5)^2 = 10$

You can obtain an equation in $x$ by substituting

$\dfrac{1}{3}(x + 6)$

for $y - 5$, which yields

$(x + 6)^2 + \left[\dfrac{1}{3}(x + 6)\right]^2 = 10$

Solve the quadratic equation for the possible $x$-coordinates of point $R$.  You can then obtain the $y$-coordinate of point $R$ using the equation of the line containing $\overline{PR}$.  Subtract the coordinates of point $Q$ from those of point $R$.  Add these values to point $P$ to find point $R$.

There are two possible solutions.

Comment: Thank You So Much! I actually did some of this, and then I think I hit a dead end but now I understand it perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you rotate the point $(x,y)$ anticlockwise about the origin by $90^o$? You will find that it goes to $(-y,x)$.

Now think about rotating the point $P$ about $Q$ anticlockwise by $90^o$. Relative to $Q$ the coordinates of $P$ are $(2,-6)$ so when you rotate it, it goes to $(6,2)$. But you are also halving its length (if you want to get $R$) so that is $(3,1)$. That is relative to $Q$. So relative to the usual origin it is $(-3,6)$.

Now the coordinates of $S$ relative to $P$ are the same as those of $R$ relative to $Q$, so $S$ must be $(-1,0)$.

You can get the other possibility in a similar way.

Comment: This is a nice direct, intuitive method, at least once you understand enough about rotations in a coordinate system. Unfortunately, as far as I recall from the graphing exercises my children got in precalculus, the standard curriculum (at least in the US) concentrates on translations of coordinates and sometimes reflection through lines parallel to the axes or through $y = x,$ but not rotations of graphs in a coordinate plane. So I think a typical precalculus student ends up doing this problem a harder way.

Comment: Interesting. I am appalled by the state of maths teaching to teenagers here in the UK, I  had not realized that the US had a few minor problems ... :)

Comment: I believe the other answer to this question is what is taught in a typical US precalculus class. Guess which of the two methods I would rather use!